# Magento: Receive XML Post Data

Tags: xml, magento

In Magento, im trying to setup a route / controller that will receive XML POST data, process it, and return a response.

My route is setup properly, and my Index Controller is setup with an indexAction().  However, using Postman, when I try and POST XML data to the route, `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()` returns empty.  I've also tried `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` as well with the same results.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here.  Can you share some of your router/controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRequest()->getPost()` is a wrapper for $_POST variable
and $_POST is set for:
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
In other words, for standard web forms (sending params like username=admin&pass=mypass)

$_POST is NOT set for:
`Content-Type:text/xml`
so you will not get your xml in $_POST.

`getRequest()->getParams()` contains $_POST, $_GET, and route parameters, again you will not get your xml here.

You can check `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` class for those methods.

You must parse yourself the xml posted. You can retrieve it like this

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getHeader('Content-Type') == 'text/xml') { // don't forget to set proper content-type header when making the request
    $postedXml = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody();
    if (false !== $postedXml) {
        // process xml
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @bogdan can u please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2